# Convert Json to HTML MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Hello everyone i'm filtering data in  SelectList when click on it, data in selectlist loading from DB. So when i click i'm get json format and my problem is correct convert to html.
So here is my Controller which is correspond on filter

```
 public JsonResult Filter(string category)
    {
        var model = from e in db.Errors
                    orderby e.Category
                    where e.Category == category || category == null || category == ""
                    select e;
        return Json(model, "true",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and View

```
  <div class="row">
            <b class="text-success">Categories</b>
                @Html.DropDownList("category", new SelectList(ViewBag.Category),new{@class="dropSearch"})

            <b class="text-success">Titles:</b>
            <select>
                <option value="value">Select title</option>
            </select>
            <b class="text-success">Severities:</b>
            <select>
                <option value="value">Select severity</option>
            </select>

            <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                <input id="styleInput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="upEl" class="jumbotron">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Timestamp</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Message</th>
                    <th>Severity</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(er=>item.Timestamp)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(er => item.Category)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(er => item.Title)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(er => item.Message)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(er => item.Severity)</td>
                    </tr>
                }

            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
```

and here is my javascript

```
 $('.dropSearch').change(function() {

    var url = '@Url.Action("Filter","Errors")';
    $.get(url, { category: $(this).val() }, function(result) {
        $('.table').html(result);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I will suggest you to create a partial view, the populate it using MVC

Comment: What does your JSON look like, and what do you want to do with it (add a new row or replace the whole table as your code indicates)?

Comment: yes i want replace whole table, this my result [link](https://pp.vk.me/c617920/v617920198/f074/mkfdQ7rrmPM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In order to do what you want there are a couple of options

1) create a partial view as @Satpal suggests and have that return the HTML of the table, and fetch that with jQuery in the way you have done (rather than return JSON)

2) Return the filtered JSON (as you have done) and itterate through it in the success function in order to dyanmically build replacement html, and drop that into the table

Option 1) will transmit more data, but be slightly easier to write (as you have use MVC views to re-build the table) 
Option 2) wlll only send JSON over the wire, so will be lighter, but will need to you build the HTML dynamically.

Comment: I know how to do 1 option, but i want to work with json, and my problem is in correct display in table [link](https://pp.vk.me/c617920/v617920198/f074/mkfdQ7rrmPM.jpg)

Comment: Its really as simple as a for loop to work through each item in the array and build up the tables contents. For a more complicated (but generic) solution try https://github.com/afshinm/Json-to-HTML-Table/blob/master/json-to-table.js

Comment: that is, but a for loop in JS isn't!